# How to get Public IP in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my case, i need public IP Address. But, after research almost all documentary related to Local IP like: [Get_IP](https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip), I want something like 202.xxx not 192.168.xxx. Can someone give some advice?

Comment: have you tried it running over a sim network not emulator or wifi.

Comment: not yet, let me check

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to get the public IP of a device from within that device. This is because the vast majority of the time, the device doesn't know it's own public IP. The public IP is assigned to the device from the ISP, and your device is usually separated from the ISP through any number of modems, routers, switches, etc.

You need to query some external resource or API (such as [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/)) that will then tell you what your public IP is. You can do this with a simple HTTP request.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<String> getPublicIP() async {
  try {
    const url = 'https://api.ipify.org';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // The response body is the IP in plain text, so just
      // return it as-is.
      return response.body;
    } else {
      // The request failed with a non-200 code
      // The ipify.org API has a lot of guaranteed uptime 
      // promises, so this shouldn't ever actually happen.
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Request failed due to an error, most likely because 
    // the phone isn't connected to the internet.
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

---

EDIT: There is now a [Dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ipify) for getting public IP information from the IPify service. You can use this package in place of the above manual solution:

```dart
import 'package:dart_ipify/dart_ipify.dart';

void main() async {
  final ipv4 = await Ipify.ipv4();
  print(ipv4); // 98.207.254.136

  final ipv6 = await Ipify.ipv64();
  print(ipv6); // 98.207.254.136 or 2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e

  final ipv4json = await Ipify.ipv64(format: Format.JSON);
  print(ipv4json); //{"ip":"98.207.254.136"} or {"ip":"2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e"}

  // The response type can be text, json or jsonp
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this package `dart_ipify` that can do this work.
https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ipify

Here is an example:

```
import 'package:dart_ipify/dart_ipify.dart';

void main() async {
  final ipv6 = await Ipify.ipv64();
  print(ipv6); // 98.207.254.136 or 2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this topic recently.
After investigating the issue, I found a solution using an external API.
I am using [ipstack](https://ipstack.com/), it has a generous free tier.

- Request a free access key
- Make the following POST call
  http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
- You can extract the ip parameter from the response